# if else statement in PHP for Magento Site, need to hide on Homepage, checkout and success page

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

Here's what is currently working with not displaying on the homepage. And displaying on all other pages, need help not displaying on /checkout/cart/ and /onepage/ and onepage/successs.

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()): ?>
<?php else: ?>

(Div I am trying to display only on pages other than homepage,checkout,success)

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: in which file you have use this code ? this should be work in header file only and to check in any file you can use 

$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
 
if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    echo 'This is Magento Homepage.';
} else {
    echo 'This is not a Magento Homepage.';
}

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    echo 'This is Magento Homepage.';
} else {
    echo 'This is not a Magento Homepage.';
}
```

this should work for home page only .For hide on multiple pages you can create a array of pages and check if route name exist in that

thanks

Comment: HI Please accept the answer also if it solves your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

place below code in your header file.

for home page :

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()){echo 'this is home page';}else{echo 'this is not home page';}
```

now we will take one variable $pageIdentifier for other then home page

```
<?php $pageIdentifier = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();?> /* this identifier value will change as per page.so echo this  variable so you will get page identifier on all pages*/
```

for cart page :

```
if($pageIdentifier == 'checkout_cart_index'){echo 'this is cart page';}
```

for onepage checkout page :

```
if($pageIdentifier == 'aw_onestepcheckout_index_index'){echo 'this is checkout page';}
```

for order sucess page :

```
if($pageIdentifier == 'checkout_onepage_success'){echo 'this is sucess page';}
```

using this code you can get other pages identity and use as per your need.

Hope this will work.